# How to make Mongoose case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So we have an authentication system but I want to make it case insensitive for the email input.

The function looks like this:

```
Auth.authenticate({ email, password })
```

Auth is a mongoose Model, and the users are stored in a mongo database.
This works but it is case sensitive and some users had trouble connecting.

First I tried this code:

```
Auth.authenticate({ email: { $regex : email,$options:"i" }, password: password })
```

But I can't make it work, I always get this error: "Can't use password with String."
and I can't find on internet how to solve this.

So I tried a different method, instead of using the authenticate function I will get the user and compare the password myself like this:

```
const user = await Auth.findOne({ "email" : { $regex : email,$options:"i" } })
if (user.password == password) { return true }
```

But the thing is, the password is encrypted with mongoosePii. So when I compare the two passwords I have to encrypt the password I received from the user first like this:

```
password = await hashPassword(password)
```

But I get a different result...
The two passwords are encrypted with the same key but for some reason they don't give the same result and I can't figure out why.

I'm not sure which solution is better but both are fine for me if you know how to solve one of them.

Comment: The password is (hopefully) not **encrypted**, it is **hashed**. Often when you hash a password then the username is also part of the hash-algorithm, thus changing the username to lowercase should also return a different password hash. Store all usernames in lower-case, as suggested by @yousoumar.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yeah you're right it is hashed, i didn't know there was a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it simpler, by lowercasing every email, and having a validator on your `Schema`. This way you don't have to write any validation about emails. Like so:

```
 npm i validator
```

```js
const { isEmail } = require("validator");
const schema = Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter an email"],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate: [isEmail, "Please enter a valid email"],
    }
  },
  
);
```

Comment: A big advantage of doing it this way is that it is much faster, because [case insensitive regex searches don't use the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). (You could even store the e-mail twice, once "as authored" and once lowercased)

Comment: I don't know why but `lowercase: true` made my query fail for some reason, so i did this : `Auth.authenticate({ email: email.toLowerCase(), password })`. And i made a script to change all emails to lowercase in the db. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: It is normal, because mongoose validation fails with the emails that are registered  before the change. You did it right though. And really glad it worked out !